# How would you ask the phone number?

Tags: usage

Say that you want to call someone, but you don't know his or her number.How would you ask his or her number?

> 1. May I know your phone number?
> 2. May I have your phone number?

Comment: May I have your number, please?..........Please may I have your number?

Answer (score 3):

"May I have your phone number?" "What is your phone number?" "Would you give me your phone number?" If it's obvious from the context that you're talking about a telephone number, you might just say "number". Like, "What's your number?"